# Lower or smoothen elevation data/DEM

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I have a linear.shp that represent a road about 20m in width. It is going across tall mountains and steep hills (don't worry about the logic on how a road is going over a mountain).

I need to (change, edit, amend) the elevation data (DEM, DTEC) along the path of the linear.shp (Roads). I want to be flatten the areas where the roads run across the terrain.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bqgis%5D+smooth+dem

Comment: In addition, to lower (i.e offset values by a fixed amount / proportion), you can use the `Raster Calculator`

Comment: I having difficulty on understanding how to use the raster calculator.

Comment: Ask a more precise question. See [tour]. As it is written now, it si difficult to understand what you want to do, what you have tried and where you're stuck.